# python как подключиться к wifi windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, wifi, password

как с помощью python в windows подключиться к сети wifi в первый раз зная пароль

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам может помочь модуль **[`winwifi`](https://pypi.org/project/winwifi/)** . Он умеет подключаться,сканировать,разрывать соединение. Вот пример подключения:

```py
import winwifi
winwifi.WinWiFi.addprofile('ssid_of_router')
winwifi.WinWiFi.connect('the_ssid_of_router', 'password')
```

Если модуль работать отказывается (а такое бывает) ,то можете подключиться к сети через командную строку(средствами `subprocess`,`os` и т.п.).
Сделать это можно с помощью команды `netsh wlan connect`,но она может подключиться только к уже существующему профилю. Чтобы его создать,легче всего записать данные в XML-файл.Вот пример:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<WLANProfile xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1">
    <name>{SSID}</name>
    <SSIDConfig>
        <SSID>
            <name>{SSID}</name>
        </SSID>
    </SSIDConfig>
    <connectionType>ESS</connectionType>
    <connectionMode>auto</connectionMode>
    <MSM>
        <security>
            <authEncryption>
                <authentication>WPA2PSK</authentication>
                <encryption>AES</encryption>
                <useOneX>false</useOneX>
            </authEncryption>
            <sharedKey>
                <keyType>passPhrase</keyType>
                <protected>false</protected>
                <keyMaterial>{password}</keyMaterial>
            </sharedKey>
        </security>
    </MSM>
    <MacRandomization xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v3">
        <enableRandomization>false</enableRandomization>
    </MacRandomization>
</WLANProfile>
```

Затем ,для добавления выполнить  `netsh wlan add profile filename="myProfile.xml"`,заменив соответствующие поля.

источники: [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/winwifi/),[stackoverflowEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56721759/how-to-connect-to-wifi-network-on-windows-using-python-3),[foobar](https://fooobar.com/questions/1261330/how-to-connect-to-a-wifi-using-cmd-only),[microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/mem/intune/configuration/wi-fi-profile-shared-key)